# How to get oozie server logs to client machine

Tags: hadoop, logging, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Requirement : We need to maintain Oozie server logs at client log directory
After submitting and running the oozie jobs from command line, we are able to see the job logs by specifying sub command -log

how can we move these logs to oozie.log in a directory. As per documentation, we can specify java property -Doozie.log.dir as below

```
oozie job -config <path/to/jo.properties> -start <jobID> -Doozie.log.dir=/home/user/log
```

but it is not creating any logs in the directory.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

`oozie.log.dir` is a server configuration, so you will not be able to override that with the client for each job execution.